# Selectize.js custom rendering with static html

Tags: javascript, selectize.js

I am using the brilliant selectize.js library to generate an attractive select box with option groups. It is all working but I am stuck at the point that I cannot use the custom renderer from the examples page (Email contacts) http://brianreavis.github.io/selectize.js/ because "item" does not know of the "email" attribute. I know how to do this in javascript, but how could I define the two attributes in static html?

In js, this woulde be

```
$('#id').selectize({
  ...
  options: [
    { name: "Martin", email: "martin@asdf.at" }
  ],
  ....
}
```

I tried the following:

```
<select>
  <option value="Martin|martin@asdf.at" data-name="Martin" data-email="martin@asdf.at">
    Martin
  </option>
</select>
```

But this is not working... Finally the render function taken from the examples:

```
render: {
    item: function(item, escape) {
        return '<div>' +
            (item.name ? '<span class="name">' + escape(item.name) + '</span>' : '') +
            (item.email ? '<span class="email">' + escape(item.email) + '</span>' : '') +
        '</div>';
    },
    option: function(item, escape) {
        var label = item.name || item.email;
        var caption = item.name ? item.email : null;
        return '<div>' +
            '<span class="label">' + escape(label) + '</span>' +
            (caption ? '<span class="caption">' + escape(caption) + '</span>' : '') +
        '</div>';
    }
}
```

I would be thankful for any hints!

Regards,
Martin

Comment: Have you handled this issue? I actually want to display custom items but don't want to use ajax to get the data. Just want to do it with static HTML somehow

Comment: Hi there. Did you solve it ? I'm kind of the same ship.

Answer (score 9):

Use this example:

```
var clearhack = $('.selectized').selectize({
    valueField: 'id',
    labelField: 'name',
    searchField: ['name'],
    sortField: 'score',//this is set to 'name' on my version, but seems sortField is only used together with load-function and score-function
    sortDirection: 'desc',
    maxItems: 1,
    //only using options-value in jsfiddle - real world it's using the load-function
    options: [
        {"id":861,"name":"Jennifer","score":6},
        {"id":111,"name":"Jenny","score":6},
        {"id":394,"name":"Jorge","score":6},
        {"id":1065,"name":"Jorge Carlson","score":6},
        {"id":389,"name":"Ann Jennifer","score":3},
        {"id":859,"name":"Bobby Jenkins","score":3},
        {"id":264,"name":"Peter Jenkins","score":3},
        {"id":990,"name":"Fred","score":1},
        {"id":349,"name":"Kal","score":1},
        {"id":409,"name":"Louis","score":1}
    ],
    create: false,
    render: {
        option: function(item, escape) {
            return '<div>'
            + '<span>ID:'+item.id+'</span> '
            + '<span>Name:'+item.name+'</span> '
            + '<span>DEBUG:'+item.score+'</span>'
            + '</div>';
        }
    },
    score: function(search) {
        return function(item) {
            return parseInt(item.score);
        };
    }
});
```

Comment: This does not answer the question

Comment: Question is how to do this using static HTML

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if this will help as it's super late - but I used the following method to get captions under my select options:

html options like:

```
<option data-data='<?php echo json_encode($obj, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT) ?>' value="<?php echo $obj->id ?>"><?php echo $obj->name ?></option>
```

and then selectize code:

```
$('select#my-select').selectize({
  valueField: 'id',
  labelField: 'name',
  searchField: ['name'],
  render: {
    option: function(item, escape) {
      var label = item.name;
      var caption = item.description;
      return '<div>' +
      '<span style="display: block; color: black; font-size: 14px;">' + escape(label) + '</span>' +
      (caption ? '<span style="display: block; color: gray; font-size: 12px;">' + escape(caption) + '</span>' : '') +
      '</div>';
    }
  }
});
```

Haven't read a lot of the docs but this will work for $obj such as:

```
{ 'id': '1', 'name': 'fred', 'description': 'fred person'}
```

Just add more attributes and reference them in your render option function.

It seems selectize reads json from a data-data attribute to populate these, but I believe you can change what attribute it reads json from by passing a `dataAttr` option in the initialize.

Comment: But how to find the option tag attributes inside render ?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem couple minutes ago.
I've add little code to `selectize.js`

In function `init_select` and next `addOption` after default code, I've add:

```
    /// iterate on data attr on <option>
    $.each($option.data(), function(i, v) {
       option[i] = v;
    });
```

Paste this code below original lines:

```
var option             = readData($option) || {};
option[field_label]    = option[field_label] || $option.text();
option[field_value]    = option[field_value] || value;
option[field_optgroup] = option[field_optgroup] || group;
```

After this my render method in selectize works fine with static data attributes :)

Comment: this seems like a smart approach to solve a commonly discussed Selectize issue... think you can elaborate on this solution a bit?

Comment: @JeffSolomon what do you mean? :) do you mean the extension of selectize? This is old answer maybe problem is solved out of the box right now